# Can i store subroutines with parameters in a hash?

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I am building a project in perl/tk that will allow timers to be started to track project work. I have ground to a halt with how to store the command for a button as subroutine but with a parameter. Since the subroutine with parameter is being executed then the result being stored as the command.

How can i store a subroutine with parameter in a hash such that it will only be executed when the button is pressed.

```
#create buttons but dont pack them on the frame yet
my $info    = $mw->Button( -text => "Good",   -command => \&info_popup );
my $warning = $mw->Button( -text => "Caution", -command => \&warning_popup );
my $error   = $mw->Button( -text => "Bad",   -command => \&error_popup );
my $close   = $mw->Button( -text => "Close",   -command => \&close );
my $project1 = $mw->Button( -text => "project1", -command => \&start_timer("project1"));
my $project2 = $mw->Button( -text => "project2", -command => \&start_timer("project2"));

sub start_timer {
    my $project = shift;
    print "starting the timer for: $project\n";
}
```

I suspect what i am attempting wont be possible so would apppreciate help on how to implement a solution that can fit this criteria that pressing a button will call subroutine with specific parameter for that button.

Comment: You can try and wrap the call to `start_timer` inside an anonymous sub like `-command => sub { start_timer( 'project1' ) }`.

Comment: @dgw that's exactly what i was looking for, works like a charm, feel free to post as an answer and i will accept it.

Comment: Also seems the tk way is to use an array ref like `-command => [\&start_timer,"project1"]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using TK, the oreilly pocket guide says

> Perl/Tk Callbacks A callback is a scalar, either a code reference or a
>   method name as a string. Either of these styles can take parameters by
>   passing an array reference, with the first element the code reference
>   or method name, and subsequent elements subroutine parameters.
>   \&subroutine [\&subroutine ?, args?] sub {...} [sub {...} ?, args?]
>   ’methodName’ [’methodName’ ?, args?] Note that bind callbacks are
>   implicitly passed the bound widget reference as the first argument of
>   the parameter list. Refer to the section Bindings and Virtual Events
>   for related information.

I tested this using the code below and it works as expected

```
#create buttons but dont pack them on the frame yet
my $info    = $mw->Button( -text => "Good",   -command => \&info_popup );
my $warning = $mw->Button( -text => "Caution", -command => \&warning_popup );
my $error   = $mw->Button( -text => "Bad",   -command => \&error_popup );
my $close   = $mw->Button( -text => "Close",   -command => \&close );
my $project1 = $mw->Button( -text => "project1", -command => [\&start_timer,"project1"]);
my $project2 = $mw->Button( -text => "project2", -command => [\&start_timer,"project2"]);

sub start_timer {
    my $project = shift;
    print "starting the timer for: $project\n";
}
```

Comment: IMO it would be clearer (and more perlish) to write `-command => sub { start_timer( "project2") } `